# Where to put test files for webdriverIO testing - using docker container?

Tags: node.js, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I do not understand how to run webdriverIO e2e tests of my nodeJS application.

As you can see my nodeJS application is also running as a docker container.

But now I got stucked with some very basic things:

1. So where do I have to put the test files which I want to run? Do I have to copy them into webdriverio container? If yes, in which folder?
2. How do I run the tests then?

This is my docker compose setup for all needed docker container:

```
services:
    webdriverio:
        image: huli/webdriverio:latest
        depends_on:
            - chrome
            - hub
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444

    hub:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - 4444:4444

    chrome:
        image: selenium/node-chrome
        ports:
            - 5900
        environment:
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
            - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
        depends_on:
            - hub

    myApp:
        container_name: myApp
        image: 'registry.example.com/project/app:latest'
        restart: always
        links:
            - 'mongodb'
        environment:
            - ROOT_URL=https://example.com
            - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb/db

    mongodb:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: 'mongo:3.4'
        restart: 'always'
        volumes:
            - '/opt/mongo/db/live:/data/db'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete minimal example in this link: [Github](https://github.com/xbx/webdriverio-docker-example)

> Q. So where do I have to put the test files which I want to run?

Put them in the container that will run Webdriver.io.

> Q. Do I have to copy them into Webdriverio container? If yes, in which folder?

Yes. Put them wherever you want. Then you can run the sequentially, from a `command:` script if you like.

> Q. How do I run the tests then?

With `docker-compose up` the test container will start and begin to run them all.

Comment: Thanks for that great example. I will try to get this running for my setup. Will post you as soon as possible